# Wheres is this method/notation of option portfolio payoff design from?

Tags: option-strategies, payoff

The "desired position" in the image is a set of slopes $(0,1,-1,0)$, and a set of strike prices between these slopes $\mathbf{K}=(98,100,102)$.

The payoff is then designed by finding the positions $n_1,n_2,n_3$ in three call options

$$c_1=(0,1,1,1)\mathbf{K}$$
$$c_2=(0,0,1,1)\mathbf{K}$$
$$c_3=(0,0,0,1)\mathbf{K}$$

So that they total the desired payoff $(0,1,-1,0)$.

In this case of a butterfly spread, the required postions are $n_1=1$ $n_2=-2$ and $n_3=1$.

Any points to litterature where this method is used is appreciated.
[image: Designing a butterfly spread]

Comment: I am not sure if it is the same method, but it seems similar to this one https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/37419/replicate-a-portfolio-with-given-payoff