# Decomposing option payoffs

Tags: options, option-pricing, black-scholes

Suppose an option payoff function $$max(min(S-1, 2-S), 0)$$ To value such an option, one would decompose this function, for example, as follows: $$max(S-1, 0) - max(2S-3, 0) + max(S-2, 0)$$ Now, it can be valued using the Black-Scholes formula.

How is this decomposition (or any other solution, for that matter) obtained?

I imagine one would start by graphing the payoff function. However, I was not able to come up with any sensible solutions by using this method.

Thank you very much!

Comment: You might find [this question](https://quant.stackexchange.com/q/37419/41821) interesting.

Comment: not sure why this is closed. It is very relevant. Gary Kennedy has a paper around this "A Reduction Algorithm for a Class of Payoff Formulae"  https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=1645275

Answer (score 3):

A good strategy to find the decomposition is to first look at the graph of
$$
\max(\min(S-1,2-S),0)\,.
$$
It looks like a

- long call with strike $1$ plus
- 2 times short a call with strike $1.5$ plus
- long a call with strike $2$

With [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/t8wekp2d4w) you can
check this reasoning.

[image]

Comment: Nice tool, thanks for link

Answer (score 1):

You can also try with the following:
\begin{align*}
&\ \max\big(\min\big(S-1,\, 2-S\big),\, 0\big) \\
=&\ \max\big(S-1 + \min\big(0,\, 3-2S\big),\, 0\big)\\
=&\ \max\big(S-1 - \max\big(2S-3, \, 0\big),\, 0\big)\\
=&\ - \max\big(2S-3, \, 0\big) + \max\big(S-1,\, \max\big(2S-3, \, 0\big)\big)\\
=&\ - \max\big(2S-3, \, 0\big) + \max\big(S-1,\, 2S-3, \, 0\big)\\
=&\ - \max\big(2S-3, \, 0\big) + \max\big(\max(S-1,\, 0\big), \, 2S-3\big)\\
=&\ - \max\big(2S-3, \, 0\big) + \max(S-1,\, 0\big) + \max\big(0, \, 2S-3 - \max(S-1,\, 0\big)\big)\\
=&\ - \max\big(2S-3, \, 0\big) + \max(S-1,\, 0\big) + \max\big(0, \, S-2 + S-1 - \max(S-1,\, 0\big)\big)\\
=&\ - \max\big(2S-3, \, 0\big) + \max(S-1,\, 0\big) + \max\big(0, \, S-2\big).
\end{align*}